# Marathon/Mesos - deploy application using the same host port for both UDP and TCP

Tags: docker, mesos, marathon

I tried to deploy an application using Marathon/Mesos. It has 2 server ports, 1 UDP and 1 TCP. I want to use the same port numbers for UDP and TCP. But it will not deploy it unless I use different ports. Any ideas?

```
"portMappings": [
  {
    "containerPort": 443,
    "hostPort": 4300,
    "servicePort": 10004,
    "protocol": "tcp",
    "labels": {}
  },
  {
    "containerPort": 162,
    "hostPort": 4300,
    "servicePort": 10005,
    "protocol": "udp",
    "labels": {}
  }
]
```

I'm seeing the following error:

`2019-03-19T23:17:19.646760+00:00 controller marathon-services[4511]: [2019-03-19 23:17:19,645] INFO  Acknowledge status update for task myserver-0.24a323d4-4a3d-11e9-83a5-054546b43537: TASK_ERROR (Resource 'ports:[4300-4300, 4300-4300]' is invalid: Invalid ranges resource: overlapping ranges) (mesosphere.marathon.core.task.update.impl.TaskStatusUpdateProcessorImpl$$EnhancerByGuice$$53f09936:ForkJoinPool-2-worker-31)`

Comment: What error are you getting? This should technically be possible I believe.

Comment: I've updated the question with error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Others seem to have encountered this problem. Marathon is trying to allocate the same port twice. The solution is given in [this comment](https://github.com/mesosphere/marathon/issues/751#issuecomment-222101947) on [this github issue](https://github.com/mesosphere/marathon/issues/751)

Rewritten for your scenario:

You need to add the resource Port to mesos slave port range by adding the start parameter `--resources-port=[4300-4300,31000-32000]`.

Let me know if that works out for you.

Comment: Sorry, what is the 31000-32000 parameter for? Also, is the above parameter given to start parameter of Marathon or my application? I actually don't have privilege to Marathon's init script.

Comment: This is from this part of the docs: https://mesosphere.github.io/marathon/docs/native-docker.html#bridged-networking-mode. Is it very important that your are using exactly these ports? Please read this whole thread: https://github.com/mesosphere/marathon/issues/751

Comment: Did you resolve this issue? Was the solution/information helpful in any way? Let me know if I can help.